# Copying HTML as shown from Inspect Element in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to copy HTML as I see in the Developer Tool (maintaining indentation & line-breaking)?

For example, when I copy outer HTML of a node from Google's search page, everything becomes one line.

As I see in the Developer Tool.
[image]
Copied
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is right click and click "View Page Source" or hit control + u

And you can just copy and paste from there

Comment: What if the HTML I see is dynamically generated? For example, if I do that on the Google's page, that part of HTML does not exist (it is in the JavaScript). Also, for other pages I have tested, HTML tags were not formatted in the View Page Source, either, so I could not get the result I want.

Comment: then I guess it might just take some time to get it from inspect element, and do proper formatting, or use notepad++ and it will help get the spaces done faster, and formatting stuff, they help you use the right syntax

Comment: You mean manually indenting & breaking lines in Notepad++? Or can it be done automatically?

Comment: Im pretty sure it could be done automatically, i downloaded it but i havent opened it , but on their website it said that they were big on syntax, so there might be a button somewhere that would correct all, but if not, it will highlight the problems so you can just go there and fix it, unless you are copying alot of code, then you might want to look for an online resource that would go through the code and correct syntax errors.